# Q:ES6 map.keys() after map.delete(key)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-map

when I try these code:

```
const map=new Map([['a', 1],['b', 2],['c', 3],['d', 4],['e', 5]]);
console.log(map.keys());
map.delete('a')
console.log(map.keys());
```

the chrome console will show these:

```
MapIterator {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
MapIterator {"c", "d", "e"}
```

"b" why not show up？

Comment: it looks like a bug to me. Interestingly, if you actually consume the iterator, There is no issue console.log([...map.keys()]);

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, happens only when deleting the first key. Also `console.log(map)` prints the correct result after deletion

Comment: Yeah most probably a bug works for  deleting other enteries except firstone

Comment: This seems to affect `map.keys()`, `map.values()` and `map.entries()` but not `map.has("b")` or `console.log(map)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a browser compatibility issues, that happens with `map.keys()`, `map.values()`, `map.entries()`.

The issue occurs in `chrome` when deleting the first key but it works when well in `safari`.

Also these properties don't even work in `Mozilla`, just returns an empty Map iterator